# How do I link to parent association in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many, model-associations, belongs-to

I am trying to do what this [person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060266/rails-linking-to-parent-associations) did but with rails 5.

In my app I have two controllers and three models.

My two controllers are `OrdersController` and `ListingsController`. And my three models are `Order`, `Listing`, and `User`.

I am trying to create user-associated links on my sales and purchases pages within my `OrdersController` that link to my `#show` action within my `ListingsController`.

The links that I have on my sales and purchases page look like this:

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <tr>
    <td class="center"><%= link_to 'View The Game Your Sold', listing_path(@listing) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This is my `Order` model:

```
belongs_to :listing
belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User"
```

This is my `OrdersController`:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def sales
    @orders = Order.all.where(seller: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def purchases
    @orders = Order.all.where(buyer: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
  end
end
```

This is my `Listing` model:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :orders
has_many :fullgames

def self.search(params)
  listings = all # for not existing params args
  listings = listings.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:name]}%") if params[:name]
  listings
end
```

This is my `ListingsController`:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:seller, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :check_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def seller
    @listings = Listing.where(user: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # GET /listings
  # GET /listings.json
  def index
    @listings = Listing.all.order("created_at DESC").search(params).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
  end

  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
  end
end
```

This is my `User` model:

```
has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :sales, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "seller_id"
has_many :purchases, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "buyer_id"
```

Comment: Your question is too long , i didn't get you . Please clarify more about your question

Comment: app/views/orders/sales.html.erb (I have a list of sales that each user has made)

app/views/orders/purchases.html.erb (I have a list of purchases that each user has made)

app/views/listings/index.html.erb (displays a list of all items)

app/views/listings/show.html.erb (displays in item indivivually)

I want to make it so my users can click on an item in there sales page and purchases and have it link to 
that item in the show page.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Order Model
 class Order < ApplicationRecord
   scope :recent, -> { order("created_at DESC") }
 end

# ListingsController
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :seller, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
    @purchases = current_user.purchases.recent
    @sales = current_user.sales.recent
  end
end

# show.html.erb
# for purchases orders
<% @purchases.each do |purchase_order| %>
  <tr>
    <td class="center"><%= purchase_order %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

# for sales orders
<% @sales.each do |sale_order| %>
  <tr>
    <td class="center"><%= sale_order %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```